# Probability of getting $70 \%$ or better

Tags: probability

What is the probability of getting a $70\%$ or better on a $10$ question true/false test having not studied for the test?

Comment: Are we to assume a strategy of randomly attempting all questions?

Comment: @MarkBennet I think the "having not studied" part is supposed to imply that the answers are necessarily random.

Comment: Of course, one may already know the material on the test and not need to study for it.

Comment: @Potato But is every question answered? Is it the best strategy to answer every question? [this is not an entirely trivial question-  Some scoring systems for multiple choice are designed to discourage guessing. Or a person may choose not to answer a question they don't understand at all.]

Answer (score 2):

I’ll get you started. You must get $7,8,9$, or $10$ of the questions right. Let’s look at the probability of getting exactly $8$ questions right.

Start with a special case: you get the first $8$ right and the last $2$ wrong. The probability of getting any one question right is $\frac12$, as is the probability of getting it wrong, so the probability of this particular outcome is $\left(\frac12\right)^{10}$. Clearly this is also the probability of getting any other particular set of $8$ questions right and the other $2$ wrong. There are $\binom{10}8$ different sets of $8$ questions, and for each of them the probability that those are exactly the $8$ that you get right is $\left(\frac12\right)^{10}$, so the total probability of getting exactly $8$ right must be

$$\binom{10}8\left(\frac12\right)^{10}.$$

Can you finish it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you choose the answer at random in each case, then your probability to guess right is $\frac 12$. You have $10$ tries and you want to guess right at least $7$ times. When we look at [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) we notice that it describes exactly what we want. Hence all we need to find the probability of getting 7, 8, 9 or 10 successes, either manually by formulas on wiki or using, for example, [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-CDF%28BinomialDistribution%2810%2C0.5%29%2C6%29) to get the desired probability of $\frac {11}{64}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \binom{10}7.(\frac12)^{10}+\binom{10}8.(\frac12)^{10}+\binom{10}9.(\frac12)^{10}+(\frac12)^{10} $$